# The following code not working in android?

Tags: android

```
details.replaceAll("null", " ");
```

In the above code i am getting the String details from the database and it may get values of the form : **null,null,null,null**.

In order to remove all the "null" from the string i am using the above code, but it is not working.

what is going wrong?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replaceAll will not change the String itself, but return a new String with the replacements made. You must assign the return value to get your code to work:

```
details = details.replaceAll("null", " ");
```